# Calculating extension a block of mass being pulled

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, elasticity

A block of mass $m$ and length $l$, kept on a frictionless surface, is being pulled towards right with constant force $F$. How can we calculate the **total extension** in block? It is given that Young's modulus of the material is $Y$.

I tried drawing freebody-diagrams but with that, I get net extension as **zero**!

[image]

According to my method, we take elementary slice dx, and make freebody diagram. Balancing forces, we get $$\dfrac{ma}{l}(l-2x) = F_{extension}$$

(**Note**: Here $a = \frac{F}{m}$)

Now, we let elementary extension be $dl$, Then:

$$dl = \dfrac{F_{extension}}{AY}dx\\\Delta l = \int_0^l\dfrac{ma}{lAY}(l-2x)dx = 0$$

This seems quite incorrect. What is the correct way to understand and solve this problem?

---

Answer given was $\Delta l = \dfrac{Fl}{2AY}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea to think about slices of thickness $dx$. Let's remember what happens if the left hand side is fixed. Then each slice experiences a force $F$, and the slice of thickness $dx$ gets an extension of $\dfrac{F}{AY} * dx$. Then the total extension is the sum of the extensions of each slice: $\int_0^l \dfrac{F}{AY} * dx = \dfrac{Fl}{AY}$.

Now let's consider the case where the left side is free to move. Then the force in the far left most slice is actually zero, and in general the force at any slice is proportional to the mass to the left of it (because it has to accelerate that mass). So the force in the slice at $x$ is $F\cdot \dfrac{x}{l}$. Therefore the extension of this slice is $\dfrac{F}{AY} \dfrac{x}{l} * dx$, and so the total extension is $\int_0^l \dfrac{F}{AY} \dfrac{x}{l}* dx = \dfrac{Fl}{2AY}.$

Comment: I get your point, but how will we show this on freebody diagram? Suppose we get net force as you said, but then how to make freebody diagram? Thanks a lot for the reasoning.

Comment: For the free body diagram, I would draw a diagram like the one you have, except show the force on the white piece to the left of the shaded gray piece. The acceleration is $\dfrac{F}{m}$, so the net force must be $\dfrac{x}{l}\dfrac{F}{m}$ , and the only thing providing a force is the shaded piece, so that gives you the force stretching the shaded piece.